# Have Ctrl-a increase a number just like in vim

Tags: spacemacs, evil

In `spacemacs` `Ctrl-a` is being used to move to the beginning of the line. I'm more used to `0` to move to the beginning of the line and `$` to the end, which works in spacemacs.
`Ctrl-a` [increases numbers in vim](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Increasing_or_decreasing_numbers) and I'd like to use that key in spacemacs too. How can I do so?
I tried to unbind the keys with the following in my `.spacemacs`:

```
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-a") nil)
(define-key global-map (kbd "C-a") nil)
```

Now the key doesn't move to the beginning of the line, but it also doesn't increment numbers, it does nothing. When I use it, it simply shows "C-a is undefined".

Answer (score 12):

The package [evil-numbers](https://github.com/cofi/evil-numbers) does exactly what you need.

Comment: Why isn't this part of evil-mode?

Comment: No idea, but it doesn't help that both `C-a` and `C-x` are bound by default in Emacs.

Answer (score 10):

I've stumbled upon the same issue of preference and as suggested before, `evil-numbers` is the package for that. But while trying to set it up, it was surprising that `evil-numbers` is already in spacemacs, just missing the keybinds.

To activate, just add

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "C-a") 'evil-numbers/inc-at-pt)
(define-key evil-visual-state-map (kbd "C-a") 'evil-numbers/inc-at-pt)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "C-x") 'evil-numbers/dec-at-pt)
(define-key evil-visual-state-map (kbd "C-x") 'evil-numbers/dec-at-pt)
```

to your user-init and it will work with Ctrl+a and Ctrl+x combinations. (taken from the package's *.el file in git)

I don't get any conflicts with previous keybinds, i guess emacs redefines them, not overlays. (?)

Comment: Can you edit your question to have appropriate keybindings rather than telling to change them?

Comment: Ofcourse i can :)

Answer (score 6):

Emacs doesn't have a built-in function to increment numbers, so [let's grab this one from EmacsWiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IncrementNumber):

```
(defun increment-number-at-point ()
  (interactive)
  (skip-chars-backward "0-9")
  (or (looking-at "[0-9]+")
      (error "No number at point"))
  (replace-match (number-to-string (1+ (string-to-number (match-string 0))))))
```

Now we can bind `C-a` to that function:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-a") 'increment-number-at-point)
```

---

Here's a version of that function that keeps point at the same place instead of moving to the end of the number:

```
(defun increment-number-at-point ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((old-point (point)))
    (unwind-protect
        (progn
          (skip-chars-backward "0-9")
          (or (looking-at "[0-9]+")
              (error "No number at point"))
          (replace-match (number-to-string (1+ (string-to-number (match-string 0))))))
      (goto-char old-point))))
```

Comment: After the increment the cursor moves to the end of the number. How can we avoid this behavior?

Comment: I edited the answer and added another version of that function that seems to keep the cursor in place.

Answer (score 1):

There are different bindings for this functionality in spacemacs.
You can increment with <kbd>Space</kbd> <kbd>n</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>Space</kbd> <kbd>n</kbd> <kbd>=</kbd> and decrement with <kbd>Space</kbd> <kbd>n</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd>.

For more information take a look at the official documentation: https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/master/doc/DOCUMENTATION.org#increasedecrease-numbers
Or this issue on GitHub: https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/9895

(On the `develop` branch these currently open a transient state in which you can further increment or decrement the values.)